# Where to find assistance with larger code blocks, Python

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've been trying to make a very basic text-based Arena-style Role-Playing Game with Python, in order to teach myself to use the system via experience.  However, I'm reaching a point where my overly-basic coding is becoming exponentially less efficient.

Is there a place like SO for more generic assistance?  Somewhere, e.g., where I could upload the code in full (it's all one 1000-line file) and ask people for generic advice for streamlining my code, where to find shortcuts, advice for helpful imports, etc.?

If there isn't anything to fit that bill, is there a place that's acceptable to post my code in full in order to point to it in questions in SO, instead of small snippets?  Or is it acceptable to post the full code here behind scrollbars?  I know that SO promotes very specific questions, but I'm guessing that just a quick scroll-through would suffice for someone to say, "You know, you can reference all of those variables simultaneously with xxxxx.xxxx!"  And that would save me days!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be the right place to post this.

Comment: Even though the site requests specificity beyond what I wanted, judging by the existing questions, it looks perfect.  I will get a lot of excellent usage from something like this.